# Is this the correct way to remove a timer?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm not sure if the way I did makes the garbage collector remove the timer. Here are my two functions:

```
public function newWave() {
    var callTimer:Timer = new Timer(800);
    callTimer.start();
    leftToSpawn = 4;
    callTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,waveCall);
}
public function waveCall(e:TimerEvent) {
    leftToSpawn--;
    if(leftToSpawn <= 0){
        e.target.stop();
        e.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,waveCall);
    }
    spawnEnemy();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove an event listener you need to remove it with the exact same signature.

If you do:

```
.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,waveCall);
```

Then you need to use the same event type and function to remove it:

```
.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,waveCall);
```

Using `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE` here will try to remove a listener that doesn't exist, which is silently ignored.

Using `target` here is ok, for other listener types you may need to use `currentTarget`, which is always the object the listener got added to. For example in a mouse click event, `target` could be a child of a MovieClip and without any listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, timer already has ability to repeat specified number of times and the correct code will be like this:

```
public function newWave() {
var callTimer:Timer = new Timer(800, 4); //repeat 4 times
callTimer.start();
callTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,waveCall);
}

public function waveCall(e:TimerEvent) {
spawnEnemy();
}
```

Comment: It is still possible to reset the timer and use it again when it stops after 4 times. The listener would still be there. It's a garbage collection question so I guess that's not the answer glados is looking for. Still it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

just change:

```
e.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,waveCall);
```

to

```
e.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,waveCall);
```